# Unrecognized selector sent to instance when extending UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, selector

I've searched through all similar questions but I couldn't find the answer.  I'm completely stumped on this... I have a class that extends UIImageView.  So here's my .h file:

```
@interface Paper : UIImageView {
@public
    CGFloat drag;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat drag;
@end
```

I'm synthesizing `drag` properly in my implementation.

Now, in my ViewController, I create and initialize a Paper object like so:

```
NSString *tempPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"picture" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *tempImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:tempPath];
Paper *tempPaper = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: tempImage];
```

The object is created right, I can later display it as a subview and all that jazz, but when I try to change my custom property immediately after the above using a line like:

```
tempPaper.drag = 1.0;
```

or

```
[tempPaper setDrag:1.0];
```

I get `[UIImageView setDrag:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` as an error.  I have tried every different method I've found but it won't allow me to set the value of my custom properties (the non-UIImageView ones) for the Paper class.  What is it I'm missing?  I've spent 2 hours on this and it's driving me nuts, I don't see what's wrong.

I've also tried initializing `drag` in Paper's `initWithImage` method, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Paper *tempPaper = [[Paper alloc] initWithImage: tempImage];
```

Comment: You are my hero, this fixed it... I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it forced me to wait 10 minutes before I could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Create object of Paper class instaed of UIImageView.

Paper *tempPaper = [[Paper alloc] initWithImage: tempImage];